# move range of rows down in vba

Tags: vba, rows, move, offset

I am trying to select the first 7 rows of my spreadsheet (the exact number could vary) and move it 32 rows down (number of rows to move down could also vary). Could someone help me with the code? I have tried:

```
Worksheets("Report").Cells(x1, 5).EntireRow.Offset(32, 0).Select
```

I also tried

```
for i = 1 to 7
set x1 = worksheets("Report").Cells(i, 5)
Rows(x1).EntireRow.Offset(32, 0).Select
```

Won't work either. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 10):

This does what you ask, and if there are any rows after 32 shifts them down:

```
Sub MoveRowsDown()
Dim NumRows As Long
Dim TargetRow As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

NumRows = 7 'change as necessary
TargetRow = 33 'change as necessary
Set ws = ActiveSheet ' change as necessary

ws.Range("A1").Resize(NumRows).EntireRow.Cut
ws.Range("A" & TargetRow + NumRows).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

EDIT: Here's a version that just cuts and pastes, with no fancy inserting:

```
Sub MoveRowsDown()
Dim NumRows As Long
Dim TargetRow As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

NumRows = 7 'change as necessary
TargetRow = 33 'change as necessary
Set ws = ActiveSheet ' change as necessary

ws.Range("A1").Resize(NumRows).EntireRow.Cut Destination:=ws.Range("A" & TargetRow)
End Sub
```

Comment: it adds a bunch of rows, but doesn't copy. If you let show me how to copy and paste a row, I might be able to modify it to my needs. Thanks.

Comment: After the downshift you can `ws.Range("A" & TargetRow + NumRows).PasteSpecial` ...I think.

Comment: In this case the shift down also copies the rows, just like `Insert Cut Cells` in the Excel interface.  I assume you are running it exactly as above.  At any rate, I'll edit to just do a cut and paste.  FYI, if you don't know about the Macro Recorder, it's a great way to get some starter code for things like this.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Sub marine()

ActiveSheet.Rows("32:38").Value = ActiveSheet.Rows("1:7").Value
ActiveSheet.Rows("1:7").Clear

End Sub
```

replace activesheet with your sheet name. activesheets are not the best

Comment: This works great unless there's formulas that need to be copied.  It also won't copy formats, comments or validation, just the values.

Comment: I like your macro name!

Answer (score 1):

Just found this:

```
range("A1:C6").Cut range("A10")
```

Sweet!

I'd also try:

```
rows("1:7").cut rows("32")
```